# Как узнать включен ли js у пользователя?

Tags: javascript

Собственно, вопрос такой. Как узнать .включен ли js у посетителя сайта? и если нет, перевести его на другую страницу. Как это сделать? На сервере есть php, но лучше бы какими-либо средствами базовыми html, meta или еще чего. Спасибо

Comment: Проще наоборот, с включенным js записывать куки о наличии js и обновлять страницу. А можно вообще сделать главную не очень зависящей от js и ничего не обновлять.  
А еще можно забить на поддержку не-js клиентов, потому что его больше почти никто не блокирует, а если и блокирует, то может делать исключения для конкретных сайтов.

Comment: Можно попробовать проверить опцию javascript через функцию php get_browser. Но лучше посмотреть в сторону Progressive Enhancement или Graceful Degradation.

Comment: @lampa, то же самое. Редиректа нет, meta выводится как текст.

Comment: @VenZell очень странно. У меня и в firefox и в chrome всё отображается так, как было задумано. Плюс проверил на удаленной машине в ie - всё нормально.

Comment: @lampa, несколько раз все перепровил. Проблема была в одном из расширений для браузера. В режиме "Инкогнито" все было ок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=noscript.html">
</noscript>
```

Размещать можно в head или в body

Comment: После ";" нужен пробел. И стоит добавить, что этот тэга надо разместить в блоке **head**.

Comment: @VenZell этот код будет работать в любой части страницы и вместо тега <meta> можно вставить любой текст, который должен отображаться, когда js отключен в браузере.

Comment: В последнем хроме с отключенным javascript выводится сам тэг с его содержимым...

Comment: @VenZell я о том и пишу.

Comment: Я под вечер туплю? Сам тэг выводится как текст. Редиректа нет.

Comment: @VenZell мне кажется, вы что-то не так сделали =))))

Comment: @lampa вот код:

<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>IU Webmaster redirect</title>
        
      </head>
      <body>
        <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=no-js.html" /></noscript>
      </body>
    </html>

В чем косяк, ума не приложу. Но я же теперь спокойно не усну, пока не пойму, в чем ошибка)

Comment: @VenZell http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q6VcB/1/show/
доктайп такой-же

Comment: Да, с пробелом правильнее. Добавил его и информацию, где размещать.
У меня в последнем хроме код работатет и там, и там при отключенном js.